# Error, Screen messes up on boot but works in safe mode, Win XP

Tags: windows-xp, laptop, dell-precision

I've recently crashed and re-installed Windows XP on my Dell M4300. Completely removing all old data. After installing windows, I updated everything via Windows Update so that everything is good to go.

Now, when I startup windows xp, I get the normal Win XP splash screen: 
[image]

After it loads, the screen immediately changes to this: [image]

And it will stay that way until I manually shut it off. Upon turning it back on, the exact same thing happens. Notice that the messed up screen always looks differently: [image] (notice the different colors)

However, I can start up in safe mode just fine! No problems whatsoever!

What could be causing this and how can I fix it?

Comment: Add the screenshots along with the question not in other site.

Comment: I would but I'm new to SuperUser and am not allows to post images until my rep is > 10. Too bad stackoverflow doesn't amount for anything here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you installed the proper display driver for your model? Enter your Service Tag on the Dell Support site, download the XP video driver, install in Safe Mode, reboot and see if that solves the issue.

Comment: I did a system restore and re-installed all the drivers except for any video-related drivers. That must have been the issue. The video driver I had downloaded before is compatible, but apparently it conflicts with something. Thanks for guiding me in the right direction!